# Boot straight to movie collection

Tags: boot

how can i boot into a folder on an external hard drive (the hard drive has media on it - i simply want to be able to select the media and play it). i am trying to make a setup where an 82 year old relative can merely turn the pi on and then pick a video and play it (no surfing around in folders etc).

the hard drive is already mounting just fine. and i have it set up so that it automatically mounts on boot.

any help would be great - thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please try to reformulate the title? It's very non-descriptive at best and misleading at worst.

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? What parts are you confused about? What good exactly is a device that boots strait to one movie? What if the 82 year old doesn't want to watch that movie, or doesn't want to watch it for the 800th time?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to set up Kodi to default to the Movies screen on boot.

In the `Settings -> Appearance` menu go to the `Skin -> Startup` menu and set it to Movies. 
If you then go into `Skin -> Settings` you have some options for removing menu items, which should help you to further simplify the interface and minimise the possibility that your relative will navigate into unfamiliar territory.